# integrating images in ruby command

Tags: ruby, rhomobile

I have an index.erb and now I want to show a picture dependent on a condition. 
So, I choose a If loop, but I don´t know how to call up a image written in html within a ruby command? Perhaps it´s easy, but I don´t have any idea, because i´m a newbie ;).

```
<%= if (condition 1 < 40)  then
           picture 1
         elsif (condition 2 > 70) then
          picture 2
         else
         picture 3 end %>

<img src="/public/images/picture1.png">
<img src="/public/images/picture2.png">
<img src="/public/images/picture3.png">
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if whether this is what you want, but I'd try anyway...

```
<% if condition 1 %>
  <img src="/public/images/picture1.png">
<% elsif condition 2 %>
  <img src="/public/images/picture2.png">
<% else %>
  <img src="/public/images/picture3.png">
<% end %>
```

Change condition 1 and condition 2 with any conditional code you want...

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I´m searching for.